# Nested SVG viewBox and preserveAspectRatio to align <image>

Tags: image, svg, viewport, viewbox

I am constructing an svg using D3.js. Inside it I am using `<image>` to place two types of images `img1` and `img2` where both have same width `W` but `img1` is shorter than `img2` i.e. `H1<H2`.

[image: the two candidate images]

They should be placed within the outer svg in a rectangle with dimensions `W`x`H2` at position `(x,y)` and the shorter one (`img1`) should be aligned vertically at the bottom of this rectangle like this:

[image: both images overlayed]

This sounds like a job for `viewBox` & `preserveAspectRatio` so I tried creating a nested `<svg>` element with dimensions `W`x`H2` (the larger of the 2 heights) at position `(x,y)` and depending on the image dynamically added each time, the layout (here shown with both images) would be:

[image: overall SVG layout with both images]

Sample code with W=35, H1=19, H2=88, x=100, y=200:

```

```
<svg...> <!--outer SVG-->
    <svg width="35" height="88" x="100" y="200" viewBox="0 0 35 88" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"> <!-- nested SVG-->
        <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="img1_OR_img2" width="35" height="CORRESPONDING_img_HEIGHT"></image>
    </svg> <!-- end of nested SVG-->
</svg> <!-- end of outer SVG-->
```

```

The problem is that the height of the nested svg is ignored and it's the height of the `<image>` that defines the height of the rectangle. So no matter what vertical alignment I ask for through `preserveAspectRatio` in the nested svg, in the case of the shorter image `img1` it will not make a difference since the rectangle is already the height of the `img1`. If I have `<image>` always have the larger height `H2`, then the smaller image `img1` appears vertically aligned in the middle.

Should I be using a whole different substructure instead of a nested svg or am I misusing the `viewBox`/`preserveAspectRatio` combo?

Note: regarding the topic `viewBox` & `preserveAspectRatio`, I used [this article](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/) which is the best I've found online so far (kudos to Sara for an amazing article).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are changing the heights.  In both cases you should be using 88 for "CORRESPONDING_img_HEIGHT".  You need to use the same viewport for both images and let SVG position the image within the viewport according to the `preserveAspectRatio` setting.

In fact, you don't need to be using nested SVGs.  The `<image>` element also has a `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image x="100" y="200" width="35" height="88" xlink:href="img1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"/>
    <image x="100" y="200" width="35" height="88" xlink:href="img2" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"/>
</svg>
```